# How I can bind a XDocument obect to DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

hi  I want to include my XDocument Object in a DropDownList in ASP.NET.

My ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpLogLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack=true onselectedindexchanged="drpLogLocation_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

My C# Code:

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\location.xml"));



                   x.Root.Descendants()
                                     .Where(e => !ActiveUserList.Contains((string)e.Attribute("group")))
                                     .ToList()
                                     .ForEach(s => s.Remove());


                   drpLogLocation.DataSource = x;// ?????????????
                   drpLogLocation.DataBind();
```

Here my XML structure:

```
<plants>
  <plant id="DB" display="Dill" group="NPS_DB" />
  <plant id="SB" display="Süd" group="NPS_SB" />
</plants>
```

I want for my DropDownList DataTextField="display" and DataValueField="id". How I can do this

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Yourxmlfile.xml");
        var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("publication")
                    select new ListItem(xEle.Element("name").Value, xEle.Attribute("tcmid").Value);

        ddlList.DataValueField = "value";
        ddlList.DataTextField = "text";
        ddlList.DataSource = query;
        ddlList.DataBind();
```

**Use Linq instead it would be better solution **

Answer (score 1):

you can get DataSet from XMLDocument and set the dropdown like this

```
  string xml = @"<plants>  <plant id='DB' display='Dill' group='NPS_DB' />  <plant id='SB' display='Süd' group='NPS_SB' /></plants>";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
        ddlList.DataValueField = "DB";
        ddlList.DataTextField = "Dill";
        ddlList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlList.DataBind();
```

or

```
XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"Yourxmlfile.xml");
DataSet ds = doc.DataSet;
```